# Neo4J - To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"

Tags: neo4j

### EDIT 1

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException: Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version. To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter "allow_store_upgrade=true"
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.checkConfigurationAllowsAutomaticUpgrade(ConfigMapUpgradeConfiguration.java:39)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.StoreUpgrader.attemptUpgrade(StoreUpgrader.java:71)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.tryToUpgradeStores(StoreFactory.java:144)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFactory.newNeoStore(StoreFactory.java:119)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreXaDataSource.start(NeoStoreXaDataSource.java:323)
    at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:503)
```

This is a static data set...it is the Cineasts example from Neo4j.  I think I echo a lot of people in saying "why do they have example data sets that are still on old versions?"

### ORIGINAL

I am trying to connect to a database through Java code like so

```
if (graphDatabaseFactory == null) {
    graphDatabaseFactory = new GraphDatabaseFactory();
}
graphDb = graphDatabaseFactory
              .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(databaseLocation)
              .setConfig(GraphDatabaseSettings.allow_store_upgrade, "true")
              .newGraphDatabase();
```

I am getting the following error...

```
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.storemigration.UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException:
    Failed to start Neo4j with an older data store version.
    To enable automatic upgrade, please set configuration parameter
    "allow_store_upgrade=true"
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I haven't answered because technically you are doing the right thing, the same thing I did (worked) using properties based config.  Can you post the longer stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the [docs](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/deployment-upgrading.html):

> Each Neo4j version supports upgrading from a limited number of previous versions.

E.g. when your dataset is on 1.8, you need first use 1.9, then 2.0 and finally 2.1 to fully upgrade. My suspicion is that your dataset is pretty old and you need to upgrade stepwise. See an old blog post of mine for that at http://blog.armbruster-it.de/2012/06/upgrading-an-old-neo4j-database-using-groovy/.

Comment: How can I tell what version the original database is?

Comment: Read the first 15 bytes of `neostore.nodestore.db`, decode them as UTF-8. This gives you the store version. Correlate that to `ALL_STORES_VERSION` in  `community/kernel/src/main/java/org/neo4j/kernel/impl/nioneo/store/CommonAbstractStore.java`.

Comment: This may be the case, but it's a disappointing choice of exception if it is. I think Cineasts was built against 1.8.1 (from pom file), so it fits with what you've said.